# angular2 mdl apply css class dynamically to material icon

Tags: angular, angular2-mdl

I am trying to apply a css class to material icon like following:

```
<i ngClass="{task.isDone ? 'checked-icon material-icons' : 'material-icons'}">check_circle</i>
```

without condition it would look like this (which works):

```
<i class="checked-icon material-icons">check_circle</i>
```

I have a variable isDone in my component and I want to apply this extra checked-icon class only when that variable is true. But my conditional statement do not work.

What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.:** I tried following

```
<i ngClass="{task.isDone ? checked-icon material-icons : material-icons}">check_circle</i>
```

but it applied this extra class to every element regardless of value false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
[ngClass]="{'className1': task.isDone, 'className2': !task.isDone }"
```

if you want `material-icons` class in common use normal `class="material-icons"` along

in your case

```
<i class="material-icons" [ngClass]="{'checked-icon':task.isDone}">check_circle</i>
```

Comment: If material-icons is common then what could be the className2? In my case I just want to apply extra checked-icon along with material-icons when a condition is true otherwise material-icons alone